# Bash script to get the total size of the folders in the s3 bucket

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a bash script to get the total size of sub folders in a S3 bucket.

My bucketpath **s3://path1/path2/subfolders**

Inside the path2 folder i have many sub-folder like

```
2019_06
2019_07
2019_08
2019_09
2019_10
2019_11
2019_12
```

I need to get the size of each subfolder in a bash script.

I wrote a script like

```
    #!/bin/bash

    FILES=$(mktemp)

    aws s3 ls "s3://path1/path2/"  >> "$FILES"

 cat $FILES
echo

for file in $FILES
do    

  if [ ! -e "$file" ]      
  then 
s3cmd du -r  s3://path1/path2/$file
   echo "$file"; echo
   continue               
 fi 

echo
done
```

The output of cat $tmpfile is as below

```
2019_06
2019_07
2019_08
2019_09
2019_10
2019_11
2019_12
```

But am getting error. While passing the variable into the **for loop**. Ideally my aim is like for each iteration when for loop runs inside **do** .....The command should be like

**s3cmd du -r s3://path1/path2/2019_06**

**s3cmd du -r s3://path1/path2/2019_07**

**s3cmd du -r s3://path1/path2/2019_08**

etc...

So that i can get the total size of the folder

Kindly help!

Comment: What do you think `i<=$tmpfile` does?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica $tmpfile conatins the output(sub-folders of the S3 bucket). I  need to pass that subfolders in the for loop to get the total size of each folder

Comment: That's not what I asked. What do you think `i<=`"the output(sub-folders of the S3 bucket)" does then?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica i<= is a condition in a for loop.It will check each line in the file $tmpfile

Comment: I know what `<=` means. What do you think it means to use `<=` with a filename on the right side?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica i think <= won't work with the file name on the right side

Comment: So why did you write code that you think won't work?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica am sorry, am new to linux...Just started
Can u pls help me

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I have changed my code.. and edited also in the question section..

Comment: @Kanagambala : _The output of cat $tmpfile is as below_ I don't see a variable with name `tmpfile` in the code you posted. Also, your `for` loop does not make much sense. `FILES` is the name of the file you have created before. Hence the loop is executed exactly once, with `file` set to `FILES`. You could simply remove the loop and just set `file=FILES`.

Comment: @user1934428 I have modified the code...Could u pls make changes in that

Comment: @Kanagambala I still don't see any difference, so I think the two issues I mentioned in my comment still apply. Actually, looking at the time stamps, the last edit you did on your question was done before my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `xargs`:

```
aws s3 ls "s3://path1/path2/" | xargs -n1 -I{} s3cmd du -r "s3://path1/path2/{}"
```

Comment: I ran as u suggested ...my output is like 0        0 objects s3://Path1/Path2/PRE 2019_06/
am getting 0 objects